# Selective HTML encoding (everything but certain tags) in .NET?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xss, html-sanitizing

I need to display a string content (that I don't have control over) on a web page. Everything should be displayed as is except certain limited number of HTML tags (strong, em, p, br). Those should be honored and my understanding is that its safe to leave them unescaped. Everything else should be displayed as is.

Surprisingly most of HTML Sanitizers are really intrusive in a sense that they are geared toward removal of something they consider 'unsafe'. Why is that? Why are they not defaulting to escaping instead of removing? Should I reserve to a hack along the lines of

```
var encoded = System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode("string content");
var encodedWithSafeTagsReenabled = encoded.Replace("&lt;strong&gt;", "<strong>");
```

Is there a cleaner and more robust way to do this in .NET ecosystem in 2016? Again, honor white list of tags and preserve (encode, not remove) everything else?

* To clarify, this will be used to place content in a specific div on the web page (I know that encoding should be context dependent based on OWASP XSS cheat sheet).

Comment: Most HTML sanitizers rely on actually building a document model and working with the nodes, rather than trying to mangle a string. As a result, invalid HTML either has to be removed or otherwise "fixed" or the building the document model will fail.

Comment: Thank you, understood. They build DOM or whatever, but my question is why are they not defaulting to encoding when dumping to a string at the end? Why do they have to be intrusive and remove? What if the content is not even a valid DOM? I'm asking them to sanitize arbitrary string for html output (not check html validity).

Comment: Again, *that's how they work*. When dealing with something like HTML, you either have to 1) Use regular expressions, which are expensive and error prone or 2) construct some sort of in-memory, class-based representation to do modifications, and then flatten it back into a string. Most libraries that work with HTML opt for the second path, which means they must rely on *standards* for how to build that object graph. That further means that anything that doesn't follow those standards (invalid) must be discarded or otherwise dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Removing is of course the most safest option. If we only html encode it, it could be un-htmlencoded if there is somewhere else a XSS bug.

For example this jQuery script:

```
var searchText = searchstring.text();
if(noResults)
{
    $("div.noResults").html("no results found for <b>" + searchText + "</b>"); //boom
}
```

> Is there a cleaner and more robust way to do this in .NET ecosystem in 2016? Again, honor white list of tags and preserve (encode, not remove) everything else?

You could do that with the [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlSanitizer/)) library and use the  `RemovingTag` event:

```cs
var sanitizer = new HtmlSanitizer();
sanitizer.RemovingTag += (sender, args) =>
{

    var tag = args.Tag; 

    args.Cancel = true;
    tag.OuterHtml = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(tag.OuterHtml); 

};
```